# Display different input for day month and year separately from datefield - django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

In the template, I would like to display each field (day, month, year)  separately  from the `AboutForm` and not just one input, something like this:

[image]

models.py:

```
class About(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    dob = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    present_address = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    permanent_address = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

forms.py:

```
class AboutForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = About
        exclude = ('user',)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the SelectDateWidget widget.

```
from django.forms import extras

...

class AboutForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = About
        exclude = ('user',)
        widgets = {
            'dob': extras.SelectDateWidget(years=range(1900, 2015))
        }
```

Thanks to likeon for pointing out that this is built in to Django.

Comment: Where do I keep the `SelectDateWidget` class? In the forms?

Comment: You can put it in forms.py before you define the form, or you can put it in a separate file (say, widgets.py) and import it at the top: `from widgets import SelectDateWidget`

Comment: Ok! Thank you. Its working. But how do I change none or the initial value `---` to be `Day` `Month` and `Year`.

Comment: Never mind, got it! Thank you for your help! Its now working perfectly.

Comment: Actually django already has SelectDateWidget in django.forms.extras.